# weird noise when I use the clutch

Tags: clutch, subaru, wrx

When I push my my clutch in at a stop it makes a weird whining noise, if I release the clutch it stops but when I push the throttle it starts again, my vehicle is a 2005 subaru wrx, the gears all shift the same, and the throttle is still very responsive, no slipping or anything. just the odd noise, what could it be?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like a failing throwout bearing. When the clutch pedal is depressed the part that actually moves the fingers or diaphragm of the clutch is the throwout bearing. While the clutch is disengaged the flywheel and pressure plate assembly are still spinning at engine speed. With the clutch the face of the bearing spins while the backside is stationary and attached to the clutchfork. The bearing only spins while the clutch is depressed and that is when you hear the noise. The bad news is that replacement requires that the transmission be removed.

Comment: FYI: my 2004 WRX has whined at me in exactly this way for the last 100,000 miles.  Mike is right about what's making the noise but, at the same time, it might turn out not to matter.  Keep an ear on it.

Answer (score 1):

Very very likely to be the clutch release bearing(throwout). Clutch pedal operation will feel slightly differant slightly harsher if it is the bearing, but in some cases just the same as before any noise. In one or two instances I have found a noise which seemed to be a release bearing that turned out to be the transmission imput shaft bearing wearing. Is your gearbox oil level up to the mark?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the throwout bearing, the only thing else to check would be an accessory belt pulley/bearing going bad. If the bearing is just starting to deteriorate, the load on the engine as one accelerates can cause the bearing to whine and sound very similar to a dying throw-out bearing.

Answer (score 0):

thrust bearing is the problem. I also had a same problem with my polo, someone told me to buy the whole cluch kit that would cost me R1300 guess what, I got that bearing for R70.